# $\int_{0}^\pi\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{(a-b\cos(\theta))^{3/2}}d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

As stated in the title.
$$\int_{0}^\pi\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{(a-b\cos(\theta))^{3/2}}d\theta$$
where $a,b$ are real, positive constants, $a \neq b$.

I tried Weierstrass substitution, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-u$, trig. identities etc. but they all seem to yield a fourth order polynomial which seems analytically intractable. Is there a (easy?) way to evaluate the integral?

Comment: Try to differentiate $(a-b\cos\theta) ^{-1/2}$.

Comment: With previous hint and integration by parts you should be able to get the integral equal to $\frac{2}{b}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a-b\cos\theta}}\,d\theta$ and use $\theta=2t$ and reduce it to Elliptic integrals.

Comment: Please post work based on the approach I suggested. Posting questions without context is discouraged here.

Comment: If $\;\left|\frac ab\right|\le1\;$ that integral most probably diverges...

Comment: The command of Mathematica 12.2 `Integrate[
 Sin[\[Theta]]^2/(1 - c*Cos[\[Theta]])^(3/2), {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> c > -1 && c < 1]` results in $$\frac{4 K\left(\frac{2 c}{c+1}\right)-4 (c+1) E\left(\frac{2 c}{c+1}\right)}{c^2 \sqrt{c+1}} .$$

Comment: The command of Mathematica 12.2 `Integrate[
 Sin[\[Theta]]^2/(c - Cos[\[Theta]])^(3/2), {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> c > 1 || c < -1]` results in $$\fbox{$\frac{4 c K\left(\frac{2}{c+1}\right)-4 (c+1) E\left(\frac{2}{c+1}\right)}{\sqrt{c+1}}\text{ if }c>1$} .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the integrand to be real over $[0,\pi]$ we require $a>b$. Then using Byrd & Friedman 291.08 – the "most general form" for integrals containing $\sqrt{a-b\cos\theta}$ – we get after some simplification
$$I=\frac8{(a+b)^{3/2}}\int_0^{K(m)}\operatorname{sn}^2u\operatorname{cd}^2u\,du$$
where the parameter $m=\frac{2b}{a+b}$. In turn, B&F 361.34 solves this as (again, after simplifying)
$$I=\frac{2\sqrt{a+b}}{b^2}((2-m)K(m)-2E(m))$$